# Android notification every 15 minutes crashes if app is closed

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

So i'm a complete newbie in Android Studio and I'm trying to make a simple app which does the following:

The app has a string array set on the /res/values folder called "frases".
The Main activity contains a button, when it's pressed, it increments a variable that represents the index of the array to be used (i've called it "iterador") and sets a textView to the value of frases[iterador].

Then on the onCreate method of the MainActivity, I have an alarnm with setRepeating that calls a class to receive a notification each 15 minutes. The purpose of this is to both have a textview in the MainActivity and a notification that can show the value of frases[iterador].

The problem here is whenever my app is closed (not stopped from the android settings menu, just closed) I get an error saying string array is null. And even worse, after the first notification, sometimes the second one won't appear even after 15 minutes if I don't open the app in my phone (even if it isn't closed).

I've tried to fix this by making both variables static so that I can access them from the notification class, but still doesn't work.

Is there a way to fix this and make the notificactions appear even whith the app closed?

My `MainActivity` vars and `onCreate` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

//MY CODE
public static boolean primera; //APP OPENED FOR THE FIRST TIME

private Button b_corazon, b_carta;
private TextView t_frase;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


//-------------------------STRING SHOW VARIABLES----------------------
public static String[] frases; //STRING ARRAY
public static int iterador; // INDEX FOR THE ARRAY
AlarmManager alarmManager; //ALARM MANAGER





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Resources res=getResources(); //GET THE RESOURCES
    frases=res.getStringArray(R.array.cartas); //ASIGN THE STRING ARRAY TO THE VARIABLE
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //MI CODIGO

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecibeNotif.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar firing = Calendar.getInstance();  //SCHEDULED TIME
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance(); //CURRENT TIME

    firing.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
    firing.set(Calendar.MINUTE,20);
    firing.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    long intendedTime=firing.getTimeInMillis(); //SCHEDULED TIME
    long currentTime=current.getTimeInMillis(); //CURRENT TIME

    if(intendedTime>=currentTime){ //IF IT ISN'T THE TIME YET
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,pendingIntent);
    }
    else{ //IF THE TIME HAS ALREADY PASSED
        firing.add(Calendar.MINUTE,15); //ADD 15 MINUTES FOR THE NEXT ALARM
        intendedTime=firing.getTimeInMillis();
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,pendingIntent);
    }






    //SAVE THE VALUE OF ITERADOR IN THE APPLICATION DATA
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0); //GUARDAR DATO DE ITERADOR
    primera=getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("primera", true);
    iterador=settings.getInt("iterador",iterador);
    init();
}
```

My `BroadcastReceiver` notification class:

```
public class RecibeNotif extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String[] frasesaux;
        int iteraux;

        iteraux=MainActivity.iterador;
        frasesaux=MainActivity.frases;
        if(iteraux==frasesaux.length){
            iteraux=0;
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent redir = new Intent(context,direct.class);
        redir.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, redir, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.message)  //ICONO DE LA NOTIFICACION
                .setContentTitle(".////.")
                .setContentText(frasesaux[iteraux])
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

    }
}
```

<-----------EDIT------------->

Okay, so it's fixed now, the notification works quite well. The only thing that still drives me crazy is how to update the value of `iterador` at the end of the notification class so it matches with `iteraux`.

So far, i've tried to edit the value of `iterador` using the `SharedPreferences.editor` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String[] finale;
    int iteraux;
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0); //GUARDAR DATO DE ITERADOR
    iteraux = settings.getInt("iterador",iterador);
    Resources res= context.getResources(); //GET THE RESOURCES
    finale=res.getStringArray(R.array.cartas); //ASIGN THE STRING ARRAY TO THE VARIABLE
    //iteraux=MainActivity.iterador;

    if(iteraux==finale.length){
        iteraux=0;
    }
    else{
        iteraux++;
    }



    //<-----------UPDATE ITERADOR VAR IN MAINACTIVITY
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = settings.edit();
    editor2.putInt("iterador",iteraux);
    editor2.commit();

   // frasesaux=MainActivity.frases;
```

Comment: "app is closed" doesn't really mean anything in Android. Look up and understand the "Activity Lifecycle"

Comment: If you want to perform functions when an Activiity is suspended or when your app is not the active one, you need to use a service or a method to call your code at the a specific time (such as by using an AlarmManager

Comment: post the crash you see on logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity is not `alive` when you receive your notification so if you try to access the fields of `Activity` which is not `alive` , you get an exception

Solution

1.) use the `context` to get `getStringArray(R.array.cartas)`

2.) Use the same `context` to fetch data from `SharedPreferences`

---

```
public class RecibeNotif extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String[] frasesaux;
        int iteraux;
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile",0);
        iteraux = settings.getInt("iterador",0);
        //                                   ^^ your default value

        //iteraux=MainActivity.iterador;
        frasesaux=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cartas);
        // ^^ fetch the array 
        if(iteraux==frasesaux.length){
            iteraux=0;
        }
        //...
   }
}
```

Note : `static` won't make any difference because your array will only be initialized when `onCreate` will get called by the android OS so since this is not the case so hence your `static` fields will stay un-initialized mean null and 0.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! it worked. I tried to use the context before but seems like i got all the syntax wrong since it was nothing but errors. Now my notification is working properly, thanks!

Comment: I am glad that i could help , happy coding